# How to properly use DOMSelectors?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Helo, im trying to cut just a specific element and i dont know how to use domselectors which are required here. This is my "normal" selector for the element i need to get

Code:

```js
await new Pageres({delay: 2, script: `funnyScriptCensoredBecauseOfReasons`})
    .source(translationUrl, ["1920x1080"], {filename: `${imageId}`, selector: `document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[29].getElementsByTagName("div")[12]`})
    .destination("./images/")
    .run();
```

Error:

```js
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[29].getElementsByTagName("div")[12]' is not a valid selector.
    at predicateQueryHandler (eval at waitForPredicatePageFunction (:3:23), <anonymous>:9:24)
    at predicate (eval at waitForPredicatePageFunction (:3:23), <anonymous>:31:33)
    at eval (eval at waitForPredicatePageFunction (:3:23), <anonymous>:33:11)
    at eval (eval at waitForPredicatePageFunction (:3:23), <anonymous>:34:7)
    at onRaf (pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:65:25)
    at pollRaf (pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:57:15)
    at waitForPredicatePageFunction (pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:12:26)
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (file:///E:/Coding/Discord-Bots/OhHellNaw-Bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:224:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async WaitTask.rerun (file:///E:/Coding/Discord-Bots/OhHellNaw-Bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/IsolatedWorld.js:603:23)
```

Comment: `selector` probably needs to be a valid CSS selector, not a JavaScript expression. So you'd likely want something like `selector: "div:nth-child(30) > div:nth-child(13)"`?

Comment: FYI: If you want to get a unique selector for an element you can open devtools and right click the element *(in devtools)* -> copy -> copy selector.

Comment: "FYI: If you want to get a unique selector for an element you can open devtools and right click the element (in devtools) -> copy -> copy selector." Cant do that bc of trashy random class names. Every time u access the site, the classes have new random names

Comment: Apparently i forgor to include a tag called "c-wiz", after adding it, it works. Thanks anyways